How can I set the dates of a html element with Python/Selenium
I need to download data files from some marketplaces every day. The problem I'm facing is that those sites have got different styles of elements to set the date and I don't have such knowledge in HTML, what makes me getting lost.
For example, how can I set a date on this datepicker?
I've tried to think about doing it by "clicking" on the days elements, but didn't make it to work. Besides, it didn't seem to be the most efficient way to do it.
